# How is arrowhead said?

Tags: meaning, word-choice

So I found some ways in saying arrowhead but found various.
One is 矢じり　「やじり」 and the other one is 石鏃　「せきぞく」
Honestly I got confused with the two. Is 矢じりa Japanese arrowhead or any kind? same question for 石鏃。

Answer (score 3):

The word recognized by laypeople is **矢じり**. People simply say 矢の先端, too.

石鏃 is a technical term for "arrowheads made of **stone**" as the kanji 石 suggests. See [this Wikipedia article](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%9F%B3%E9%8F%83). This 鏃 (on: ソク/ゾク, kun: やじり) is a single-character kanji for "arrowhead", but this is not a joyo kanji and most people cannot read it without furigana. Arrowheads made of iron are specifically called 鉄鏃.

Answer (score 0):

[矢]{や}　　　：arrow
[矢]{や}じり　：arrowhead
[矢]{や}の[先端]{せんたん}：the tip of an arrow
[矢印]{やじるし}　　：arrow symbol / arrow mark
　　　　　(this is what is used to type out arrow symbols →↖↩↑ on a keyboard)

[石鏃]{せきぞく}　　：flint arrowhead (specifically, an arrowhead made out of flint stone)